# Conditionally hide named router outlet in parent route in Angular

Tags: angular

I have some routes defined like this

```js
{
  path: ':id',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HeaderComponent,
      outlet: 'header'
    },
    {
      path: '',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'another/path'
          component: SomeOtherComponent
        },
        // ...
    }
  ]
}
```

So the parent route has an auxiliary router outlet to display `HeaderComponent` above any other component within these routes. I want to be able to disable that `HeaderComponent` for one particular route in my tree.

My last resort is to add an `*ngIf` in `HeaderComponent` to remove the whole thing if it matches a specific route, but that feels like a hack. Is there a way to define my routes to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: `I want to be able to disable that HeaderComponent for one particular route in my tree.` Could you explain that a little bit more? It seems perfectly valid to use `*ngIf` to conditionally hide elements.

Comment: I don't want to do that in the `HeaderComponent` itself. That component shouldn't be concerned with when it needs to show. I want to be able to define that behavior on the route I want it disabled for.